# How to add Generic button to navigate to another page - Angular 11

Tags: angular

This is ( [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reusable-table-gueyfj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) ) usual example for reusable table component, where i can feed data successfully. But i want to add action buttons like **ADD | Edit | Delete**. with the help action button i should navigate to another page to add/edit records. Could someone tell me how i can efficiently use `@Output` decorator here. I'll be reusing the same table for other different components.

nearly sitting two days to understand reusable component. i did something different. but i just found above example.

**table.component.ts**

```
@Input()
  tableColumns: Array<Column> = [];

  @Input()
  tableData: Array<T> = [];

  displayedColumns: Array<string> = [];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<T> = new MatTableDataSource();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.displayedColumns = this.tableColumns.map((c) => c.columnDef);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableData);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways to go about this:

Doing the navigation/action on the table component OR in the parent component.

The second part is what involves using an Output event emitter;
You pass the identifier of the table element into a predefined function for instance

Table Component HTML:

```
<ng-container
  matColumnDef="add"
>
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Add</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <button
      (click)="onAdd(element.id)"
    >
      ADD
    </button>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

The function emits the passed in data (id in this case) to the parent component which receives it as an emitter and fires a corresponding function as shown below

On the table Component TS:

```
@Output() addItem: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
@Output() editItem: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
@Output() deleteItem: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

onAdd(id) {
this.addItem.emit(id);
}

onEdit(id) {
this.editItem.emit(id);
}

onDelete(id) {
this.deleteItem.emit(id);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use one event emitter which emits the id and a text case e.g add, edit, delete.
And use this with a condition statement on the parent to keep things relatively smaller.

On Parent Component HTML:

```
<app-shared-table (addItem)="addSelectedItem($event) (editItem)="editSelectedItem($event) (deleteItem)="deleteSelectedItem($event)"></app-shared-table>
```

Parent Component TS:

```
addSelectedItem(id) {
//perform action
}

editSelectedItem(id) {
//perform action
}

deleteSelectedItem(id) {
//perform action
}
```

I hope this solves your puzzles, cheers

Comment: this helped me to understand the concept. so accepted your solution.. Thanks